# Java Date exception handling try catch

Tags: java, exception, formatting, parseexception

Is there some sort of exception in Java to catch an invalid Date object? I'm trying to use it in the following method, but I don't know what type of exception to look for. Is it a ParseException.

```
public boolean setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;                
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the method you provide, there is no way to catch an exception, because none will be thrown by the simple assignment.  All you can do is maybe the below change:

```
if(date == null) return false;
```

But even that's not graceful.  You may want to do something with `this.date` or throw an exception up if that's the desired behavior.

What you are really seeking is either:

1. `ParseException` - thrown by a `DateFormat` object when it attempts to `parse()`, which would happen before your set method
2. `IllegalArgumentException` - thrown by a `SimpleDateFormat` constructor, again it would happen before your set method.  Indicates you provided an invalid format string.

You'd want to catch one of those (probably #1).  But it has to happen **before** your method call.  Once you have a `Date` object, it is either `null` or valid.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be related to the original question. But you must notice the method name, which is `setDate()`. Do you think it sounds like it will return something? Or if it may, then do you think its a good idea to return a `boolean` there? IMO, do something like this,

```
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;                
}

public boolean isDateNull() { // or something
    return this.date == null;                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this method, there is no need to worry about an exception.  The date is already created by the time you get into this method.  If you are parsing a date, it would have done outside of this code.  The best you could do is make sure the date is not null.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by an invalid date. Did you mean to give us a method signature that looked more like this?

```
public void setDate(String date) throws ParseException {
   this.date = SomeDateFormat.getInstance().format(date);
}
```

Otherwise, as the others stated the simple act of assigning a Java date object to a field shouldn't be exceptional as it is either an instance of Date already, or null.

If you are just trying to parse a string into a java.util.Date, look at [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), FastDateFormat (apache, thread safe), or Joda Time.